# Can't I use classes for return and parameter in DLL?

Tags: c++, dll

I can use code like this:

```
// RendererDLL.h
#pragma once
class gfx::BaseObject;
class gfx::MeshObject;

namespace gfx {
    extern "C" {
        void __declspec(dllexport) InitGraphics(UINT width, UINT height, HWND hwnd);
        void __declspec(dllexport) ReleaseGraphics();
    }
}
```

I don't use a class for the return type and parameters. And this code works.

But I can't use code like this:

```
namespace gfx {
    extern "C" {
        void __declspec(dllexport) EnqueueObject(gfx::BaseObject* pBaseObj);
    }
}
```

or

```
namespace gfx {
    extern "C" {
        __declspec(dllexport) gfx::MeshObject* CreateMeshObject();
    }
}
```

This code uses classes for the return type or parameter type.

I get errors. First, at `EnqueueObject()`:

> linkage specification is incompatible with previous "gfx::EnqueueObject"

Second, at `CreateMeshObject()`:

> cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone

```
// RendererDLL.cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "RendererDLL.h"
#include "Graphics.h"

#include "BaseObject.h"
#include "MeshObject.h"

#include "RenderQueue.h"

void gfx::EnqueueObject(gfx::BaseObject* pBaseObj) {
    gfx::RenderQueue::GetInstance().Enqueue(pBaseObj);
}

gfx::MeshObject* gfx::CreateMeshObject() {
    return new gfx::MeshObject();
}
```

This code is in a `.cpp` file.

I think the first error occurs because of using a class for the return type or parameter type. But I don't know why.

Comment: "linkage specification is incompatible" means you have already declared the same function previously without `extern "C"`. "cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone" means you have already declared the same function previously, with a different return type.

Comment: It looks like you `extern "C"` declare them in the header but implement them without it.

Comment: Your definitions need to match your declarations including `extren "C"` and `declspec`

Comment: Be very careful when you expose C++ objects on libraries/dll's (API's). Whenever you change the memory layout of those objects ALL clients need to be recompiled. (Which for dll's can be quite unexpected)  Better to have a "C" style API, if you can't do that have a look at the [pimpl idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) this will at least allow you to refactor implementation without breaking your clients.

Comment: We need the context of the usage of your code. If the user is using C, have you declared your struct `gfx::BaseObject` in extern "C"?

Comment: Thanks all. I cleared the first error. But not the second. I added extern "C" keyword in Renderer.cpp file.

Comment: Guys, I found something surprising. I just swapped included header files (I got "RendererDLL.h" down), then it started to work! But I don't know exactly why it works. Who can explain?